# is it correct to ask "Is the class still on at 3?" . is there a better way to as this question?

Tags: spoken-english, informal-language

I have my singing class at 3 
and need to confirm with my instructor. Is this the right way to ask the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simple idiomatic "*on*" might have started out as short for "*on* the schedule". At any rate, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on) lists definition #4 of "on" (as an adjective) this way:

> **INTENDED**, **PLANNED**

Their example is, "has nothing *on* for tonight"

So your sentence sounds fine in English:

> "Is the class still on at 3?"

In *writing*, it looks a tiny bit tricky *at first* because of the two little words "*on*" and "*at*" right next to each other, but there is nothing wrong with the sentence. It is grammatical, idiomatic, natural, and easy to understand -- especially in spoken English. And, if the reader is paying attention, it is also no problem in writing.

You could also ask,

> "Are we still on for class at 3?"
>
> "Is our/the 3 o'clock class still on?"

All 3 sentences are good.